# Performance testing on host intrusion prevention system

Tags: performance, testing

I need some help here. In my current project we are replacing a Host Intrusion Prevention Software (HIPS) and I need to do performance testing on its server. Wondering if you can throw some light on what type of performance testing can be done on the server and also what kind of comparison test I can do wrt perf test for already existing HIPS server?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve, actually. Are you guys developing a Host Intrusion Prevention Software or just replacing an existing one for another from other vendor or version?

As your topic says you want to do performance testing, I will ignore all the functional testing and security testing you could do.

One thing I think you can measure is the resource consumption by the HIPS, you could compare with the previous version to know if it will need a more robust host than you actually have or if it will have some performance impact over the other applications running in the same host.